# convert string to boolean

Tags: vb.net, vba, datagridview

I got a datagridview which transfers data to a other datagridview which i would like some help with. It looks like it should be working, however i get a error saying that the string cannot be converted to boolean. This is the case for the checkbox in the datagridview(user has to click the checkboxes of the rows they want to copy.) 
I know how to convert values to strings etc but i can't seem to get this one figured out. Can anyone help me? 
This is what happens at the click of the copy button:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = True Then
            DGV2.Rows.Add(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
            '2 = voer, 3 =voerid, 4= drogestof, 6 = (voer)keukenlocatie
        End If
```

DGV1 is the datagrid where the data has to come from, so cell4 is the checkbox. DGV2 is the datagrid where the data has to go to.

Update: 
Right now i use this code, which got me a bit further.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnkopieren.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        If CBool(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value) Then
            'If DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = True Then
            DGV2.Rows.Add(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, _
            DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
            '2 = voer, 3 =voerid, 4= drogestof, 6 = (voer)keukenlocatie
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I get the error "**Invalid Operationexception was unhandled**"
Apparantly, they don't like it when i want to transfer the selected data from 1 datagridview to a other bound datagridview. Is there any solution for this? I tried fixing it myself and googling, but without results.

Comment: So you want to convert `drogestof` to a `Boolean`, how?

Comment: Surely you meant to test the CheckBox, not column 4?

Comment: Hello, no, not drogestof. DGV1 is the datagrid where the data has to come from, so cell4 is the checkbox. DGV2 is the datagrid where the data has to go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to copy the checked rows. So you should the column with the checkbox to validate that it is checked or not. If your first column is of checkbox type then it is Cell(0). Possibly modifying your code as shown below will work for you.

```
          For i As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
            If CBool(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
                DGV2.Rows.Add(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, _
                DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value, _
                DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, _
                DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value, _
                DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value)
                '2 = voer, 3 =voerid, 4= drogestof, 6 = (voer)keukenlocatie
            End If
          Next
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks! I tried using your code and removed the double (it's coded to populate cell 3 twice.) but i get a 'ArgumentOutOfRange exception'

Comment: I have not added cell 3 twice, its your code only in which I suggested you to use the checkbox column for converting to Boolean. For the exception you are getting, It means you are accessing some cell which is not available. Try checking Cells.Count and then debug your code.

Comment: Hello, No that was my mistake. ;) i'll recount the cells(though i'm quite sure it's correct ) and see if i can fix it. I found some other solutions but they are all for copying to an empty dgv so not usefull to me.

Comment: Okay, think i got the code as it should be. Now let's see how i can copy to a bound datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Value needs to be true of false string. Maybe a numeric string (0, not 0, -1, not -1), or a number.

Here's an experiment.

```
A = 0
B = 1
C = -1
D = 55

msgbox A & " " & B & " " & C & " " & D 
msgbox cbool(A) & " " & cbool(B) & " " & cbool(C) & " " & cbool(D)
msgbox cbool(cstr(A)) & " " & cbool(cstr(B)) & " " & cbool(cstr(C)) & " " & cbool(cstr(D))
msgbox cbool("true") & " " & cint(vbtrue)
msgbox cbool("false") & " " & cint(vbfalse)
msgbox cbool("cat")
```

You'll see false = 0 and true <> 0. And cat is an error.

Comment: Wow, what a hospitality. :P (No, it wasn't me who downvoted.) As for your code, i see it will open a messagebox and check if something is true or false, right?

Comment: What does still remain is my problem. Unfortunatly i didn't solve it yet.